# Getting Errorno 87(Invalid Parameter) for SetConsoleCursorPosition Function Call in Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am Writing a Console Application in C using Win32 and Tiny C Compiler.
The Environment is Windows 8.1 64 bit.
I am getting a Errorno 87 (Invalid Parameter ) When I am Calling SetConsoleCursorPosition Function.
The sample code is below.

```
 #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    COORD coord ;
    main()
    {

    int res ;
    HANDLE h ;
    char teststr[100];
    h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(h ==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return ;
    coord.X= 10;
    coord.Y = 10;
    res = SetConsoleCursorPosition(h,coord);
    if(!res)
    {
    sprintf(teststr," res= %d ; Coords : %d %d ",GetLastError(), coord.X,   coord.Y);
    cprintf(teststr);
    }
getch();
return;
}
```

Comment: Check for a null return from `getStdHandle()`. The API docs say it cna return an invlaid handle or NULL.

Comment: if handle is not valid - will be error `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` but not `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

Comment: Works compiled with Tiny C 32 bit, fails with Tiny C 64 bits. Probably bug in compiler passing small structs (COORD is only 4 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

[`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when and only when *dwCursorPosition* is ivalid - The coordinates must be within the boundaries of the console screen buffer. more exactly - need call [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) and *`dwCursorPosition`* must be within the boundaries of *`dwSize`* member of [`CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffer-info-str)

```
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

switch ((ULONG_PTR)hStdOut)
{
case NULL:
case INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
    break;
default:
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO ConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &ConsoleScreenBufferInfo))
    {
        COORD dwCursorPosition = { 10, 10};
        if ((USHORT)dwCursorPosition.X < (USHORT)ConsoleScreenBufferInfo.dwSize.X &&
            (USHORT)dwCursorPosition.Y < (USHORT)ConsoleScreenBufferInfo.dwSize.Y)
        {
            if (!SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, dwCursorPosition))
            {
                DbgPrint("SetConsoleCursorPosition - %u\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // will be be ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo - %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
```

in case invalid or not console(pipe, file, null device) handle (*`hStdOut`*) - will be `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` error.

for research this error you first must get [`CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffer-info-str) and be sure that your coord valid. if yes, you need look in debugger value of *edx* register just before call `SetConsoleCursorPosition` - it must be `0x000A000A` - if no, paste asm code, how your compiler generate initialize *edx* (or *rdx* but high part is ignored) before call `SetConsoleCursorPosition`

Comment: Daniel Sek, I have tried the 32 bit compiler and it works. Looks like a bug in 64bit version. Thanks for the help.

Comment: jdv, The GetStdHandle is returning a valid handle. When i pass the handle for other functions like GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() I am getting a valid values in return. Thanks.

Comment: RbMm, The GetStdHandle is giving a valid handle in return. When I pass the Handle to The GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() I am getting a valid values in return. The problem is with the 64 bit version of the compiler.

Comment: @harikrishnarupanagudi - show in this case assembler code of `res = SetConsoleCursorPosition(h,coord);` of download your demo exe for view